# How to replace CUDA function to single threaded CPU functions?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to debug my cuda program but i look very unpractical to me to do as it is multithreaded as you have to select the warps, and also have two debugger if you want to debug both cpu and gpu at the same time.
Also I searched for a single threaded debugging mode but it doesn't seems to exist then I decided to modify the functions when I am in debugging configuration by adding `#ifdef _DEBUG` lines.
Like that :

```
#ifndef DEBUG
__global__
#endif
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
```

And :

```
int blockSize = 256;
int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
ifdef _DEBUG
        gridDim.x = numBlocks;
        blockDim.x = blockSize;
        for (threadIdx.x = 0; threadIdx.x < blockSize; threadIdx.x++)
            for (blockIdx.x = 0; blockIdx.x < numBlocks; blockIdx.x++)
                add(N, x, y);
#else
        add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(N, x, y);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
#endif // _DEBUG
```

It could work but the compiler complain about gridDim.x, blockDim.x, threadIdx.x and blockIdx.x not beeing editable.

I tried that :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG

    #define __global__
    uint3 threadIdx;
    uint3 blockIdx;
    uint3 blockDim;
    uint3 gridDim;

#else

    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#endif
```

But it doesn't like this anymore giving a `declaration is incompatible with "const uint3 threadIdx"`.
My c++ knowledge is not enough extended to find the solution.

EDIT:
I could change all my kernels like that :

```
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  #ifdef _DEBUG
     int index=mythreadidxx;
     int stride=myblockdimx;
  #else
     int index = threadIdx.x;
     int stride = blockDim.x;
  #endif

  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
```

But it would make the code heavier again.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect example of an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your real problem is with the debugging tools (which should work absolutely fine, and the CUDA tools can debug host code) and yet you ask about your solution is to somehow try and hack an emulator for CUDA code , which seems completely nonsensical to me

Comment: @talonmies Yes my problem is with the debugging tools that are unpractical. Yes you can debug threads but threads still start wehn them want to and my needs actually is to check work in the right order to understand something wrong in my code. I can go on the thread I want with the debugger but the thread can change when hitting F10... that does what that wants.

Comment: @talonmies And I'm trying to debug "my code design" so it's not nonsensical to be able to switch to a single threaded - cpu mode to do that, cuda do its job, I don't need to debug that part of my code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some decent cuda debuggers out there which can debug cpu and gpu at the same time, specifically you could use Nvidia's tools such as [Cuda-gdb](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gdb) which can be used in visual studios or eclipse for cpu and gpu breakpoints. There are also paid for tools like [total view](https://www.roguewave.com/) or [Arm-ddt](https://www.arm.com/products/development-tools/server-and-hpc/forge/ddt).

Comment: CUDA-GDB is for linux/mac no ?

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution, I added that at the beginning :

```
#ifdef STHREADED

    #define __global__
    int threadIdxX;
    int blockIdxX;
    int blockDimX;
    int gridDimX;

#else

    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"

    #define threadIdxX threadIdx.x
    #define blockIdxX blockIdx.x
    #define blockDimX blockDim.x
    #define gridDimX gridDim.x

#endif
```

This way in my code I can use threadIdxX instead of threadIdx.x and I've been able to find the bug I was looking for by using no threading at all.